# Display Custom Post Type on Toolset Types Plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-types

I have created a custom post type with php and my problem is that this post type is not appearing in the menu of Toolset Types Plugin. I think that must be some option that I have to fill but I have tried with almost everything and I don´t know why this is happening.

I want to edit the relationship between post types, specially between cars and news.

My code to create the custom post type is this.

```
function car_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Coches',
        'singular_name' => 'Coche',
        'menu_name' => 'Coches',
        'name_admin_bar' => 'Coches',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Padre:',
        'all_items' => 'Todos los coches',
        'add_new_item' => 'Añadir nuevo coche',
        'add_new' => 'Añadir coche',
        'new_item' => 'Nuevo coche',
        'edit_item' => 'Editar coche',
        'update_item' => 'Actualizar coche',
        'view_item' => 'Ver coche',
        'search_items' => 'Buscar coches',
        'not_found' => 'No hay resultados',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No se han encontrado coches en la papelera',
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug' => 'coche',
        'with_front' => true,
        'pages' => true,
        'feeds' => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'Car', 'clever' ),
        'description' => __( 'Cars', 'clever' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions',
        ),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-dashboard',
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'rewrite' => $rewrite,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );

    register_post_type('car', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'car_post_type', 0);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your registration seems fine, the usual things that hide them from `get_post`/`WP_Query` calls are all good. I would look into how the plugin creates its list of post types. Does it even allow for custom post types?

Comment: If you create the post type with the plugin, it works. But if you do it in PHP it does not appear.

Comment: That seems to be because when registering through plugin, it is creating a option with an array value of names, and then calling that to both create the menu first, and then to register the types and taxonomies. Your post type is not in their options, so it won't be added. It doesn't appear to check for post types created outside itself.

Comment: So, do I have to generate that option? how can i do it?

Comment: `get_option( WPCF_OPTION_NAME_CUSTOM_TYPES, array() );` search the plugin directory for that line and you will see what I mean. There is a filter you can hook though: `$data = apply_filters( 'types_post_type', $data, $post_type );` at the top of `wpcf_custom_types_register()` in _/library/toolset/types/embedded/includes/custom-types.php_ line 223

Comment: I just don't know if that filter is too late for menu creation. I just scanned through it. (I *think* you would need to add your post type to that option the plugin is creating, rather than create that option for your post type. There are some others, too, for taxonomies, etc. I would trying registering via the hook I mentioned above (rather than normally) first.

Comment: One last night, as this question stands it will probably get closed as off topic b/c it is about a specific plugin's functionality. However, if you make some attempts at using those filters it makes available and get stuck, and you can provide enough succinct code to show how the pieces are connected (or how you think they are), a question on "how to use filter and action hooks provided by plugin" or "how to add my option to options created by plugin" *might* be both within scope and helpful to others. just a thought.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a solution with ACF plugin, this plugin allow to create relationships between post types when one of the post types is created with php.

You can download the plugin from here:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/